# XBee-PRO broadcast configuration

Tags: xbee, configuration

How can I configure an XBee-PRO module in broadcast mode?

We are using an AT8051 controller.

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked the manual? Here's a link from google.

http://ssdl.stanford.edu/ssdl/images/stories/AA236/0708A/Lab/Rover/Parts/xbeeproproductmanual.pdf

Section 2.4.2 states that to send a broadcast message, set the destination address to 0xFFFF.

Comment: not very magical, but when i use XBee at school it is the same.